get_template_parts() usage
I am trying to add a template sections that I have in a directory my-child-theme/template-parts/hero.php.
In my page template (my-child-theme/templates/front-page.php) I am calling echo get_template_part( '/template-parts/hero.php', 'hero' ); but I can't seem to get the template-part into the frontpage template.
Am I using this function wrong?

Yes, you are using the function wrong. You don't need to echo the return of get_template_part() – the template it references will automatically be echo-ed.
Furthermore, you don't want to have a leading forward slash (/) at the start of the first parameter, or the .php extension, nor the second parameter.
Your function call ends up looking for:
my-child-theme//template-parts/hero.php-hero.php
               ↑                     ↑    ↑
          Double slash caused        │  Extra -hero from the second parameter.
          by leading / in first      │
          parameter              Extra .php
                                 from the first
                                 parameter

Rather, you'd want:
// my-child-theme/template-parts/hero.php
get_template_part( 'template-parts/hero' );


that worked! thank you so much!
